# Prove $Z[\sqrt{2}]/\sqrt{2}Z[\sqrt{2}]$ has only 2 elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to prove that factor ring $$Z[\sqrt{2}]/\sqrt{2}Z[\sqrt{2}]$$ has only two elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** 
$$\sqrt{2} \in \sqrt{2} \mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}] \\
2=\sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{2} \in \sqrt{2} \mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$$

Use this to show that 
$$\sqrt{2} \mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}] =\{ a+b \sqrt{2} | a, b \in \mathbb Z, a \mbox{ even } \}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: analyse the ring homomorphism $\phi$: $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $\phi(a+b\sqrt2)=a$ mod $2$.

Answer (score 1):

notice that as abelian groups
$$
\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] \cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus \sqrt{2} \mathbb{Z}
$$
so
$$
\sqrt{2}\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] \cong \sqrt{2}\mathbb{Z}\oplus 2 \mathbb{Z}\cong 2\mathbb{Z} \oplus \sqrt{2}\mathbb{Z}
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] /\sqrt{2} \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] \cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus \sqrt{2} \mathbb{Z} /  2\mathbb{Z} \oplus \sqrt{2}\mathbb{Z} \\ \cong  \mathbb{Z}/ 2\mathbb{Z} 
$$